# Restoring an altered SQL Server database with an original MDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I'm using a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance and inadvertently deleted a column of id's that I would like to restore.

I have the original `MDF` and `LDF`. Can I detach my altered database and restore it to its original status by attaching a new database using the original `MDF`?

Comment: Is there any reason at all you wouldn't just try this on a test database yourself? Suppose I, a random guy on the internet, said "yes, no problem" and then you proceed to hose the database even worse?

Comment: I believe you can but please do what @JeroenMostert said and try it on a test DB first.

Comment: I dropped all connections and detached the altered database, then attached a new database using the original MDF and everything is restored. The one thing to note is that you will need to remember to re-run all scripts you may have used on the original db. Thanks!!